# Google V3 - Referencing markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a script that adds markers one by one to a map

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51,-117)
                });
marker.setIcon(getIconFile(initialIconId));
markers.push(new Array(id,marker)); // id, marker
marker.setMap(map);
```

later on in the script when I press a custom button I want to be able to change the markers icons. So I grab the marker by the id from the markers array and call:

```
 markers[markerIndex].setIcon(getIconFile(newIconId)); // which returns a string url of the icon
```

However I receive: **TypeError: markers[markerId].setIcon is not a function**

I print the markerId and it is valid, I also print the result of indexing the marker markers[markerId] and it returns a marker object. I have no other way to debug this I am lost!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're pushing an Array into the markers, instead of just one element.

Why not:

```
markers = []
markers.push(marker)
markers[markerIndex].setIcon(getIconFile(newIconId));
```

or if you insist inserting an array:

```
markers.push(new Array(id,marker));
markers[markerIndex][1].setIcon(getIconFile(newIconId));
```

Comment: Because I need to know the id of the marker. Each marker represents a truck and each truck has a unique id, using indexes wont help because it does not give me the id.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer...you can do `markers[markerIndex][1]` to get the marker